# How to change the color of active tab in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a search box with tabs on it but the problem is when I presses on the tab the active tab shows no text because I set the color to white. I want that; when i press on the tab the active tab shows text in blue color and all the other tabs show white text on blue background. I used bootstrap for this.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-left: 20px;" id="myTab" role="tablist" >
  <li class="nav-item" style="background-color:#0080FF; ">
    <a class="nav-link active " id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true" style="color: white; ">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" style="background-color:#0080FF; ">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false" style="color:white ;">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" style="background-color:#0080FF; ">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false" style="color:white ;">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent" >
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" >...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not use inline css while it's not the last resort. 
I refactor your code & edit the css as below.

It's just a problem with specificity value. You can refer to this https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

```css
.nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link {
  background-color: #0080FF;
  color: #FFF;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link.active {
  color: #0080FF;
}

.tab-content {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-top: transparent;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content .tab-pane {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #0080FF;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <div class="col-md-11">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active " id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
        laborum." Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
        et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem
        ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam,
        nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can u please help me with one more thing? I want to create a box attached with these tabs like a boundary

Comment: @CaraJ if it works, please mark it as answered. Can you also be more specific on this? "a box attached with these tabs like a boundary "

Comment: I already have marked it :) https://colorlib.com/wp/template/dorne/  check this link, I want to create a box with tabs like this

Comment: You mean the content of the tab?

Comment: Yeah, box around the content of tab but this box should be attached to the active tab

Comment: why not just update the global variable `--bs-nav-tabs-link-active-bg` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Style to change the color of active Tab in Bootstrap

```
ul.nav li.active a {color:red;}
```

You are using active class to  tag. But bootsrap given active class to

tag.

> Its all depend upon your bootstrap version.

Comment: ul.nav li.active a {color:red;}

Comment: Use this becouse bootstrap active class given to the <li> tag

Answer (score 0):

You can always modify your navigation list through css. Use this css code instead, in that way use you use the a tag to change the color and its background-color. It's improper to use the `li` tag to set the background only and `a` tag to set the color of the text. You can always combine the bg color and color of the text into one tag. And also it is not advisable to use inline css in html.

**CSS CODE**

```
ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item {display:block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;}
ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.nav-link {width:100%;display:block;background-color:#0080FF;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;}
ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.nav-link:active,.nav-item a.nav-link:hover {color:red;background-color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the distance between the tab and it's border:

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link {
        height: 56px;        
 }
```

To also change the color of the active tab's border, use:

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link.active {
 color: black;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #40A758;
}
```